# Intersection from one table

Tags: sql, intersection

I would like to get an intersection of one table.
My table constists of products which appear in several markets. How can i get the products which are in location A and B (for example this apple)?

```
product     market
apple       location A
apple       location B
orange      location C
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL 11.2 Oracle Database 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT product
FROM yourTable
WHERE market IN ('location A', 'location B')
GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT market) = 2
```

Another possibility would be to use conditional aggregation and count the number of times which a given market appears with each product:

```
SELECT product
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY product
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN market = 'location A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND    -- appears in A
       SUM(CASE WHEN market = 'location B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0        -- appears in B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through 'INNER JOIN' as below

```
select t.product
from product t
inner join 
      (select product from product where market = 'location A') tt on t.product = tt.product
where market = 'location B'
```